# Can't filter values > 0 using textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a textbox to filter some money values but instead of getting me all the fields of gridview it refreshes the webpage. I want to only filter values from gridview where I can only filter values > 0. How can I fix my problem here?

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Filter data using textbox//
            string filter = "";
            string command = "SELECT * FROM NaoMatch WHERE Cliente is not null And";
            if (TextPesquisarDataMovimento.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + "  [Data Movimento ] LIKE '%" + TextPesquisarDataMovimento.Text + "%' AND";
                Debug.Write(filter);
            }
            if (TextPesquisarDataValor.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " [Data Valor] LIKE '%" + TextPesquisarDataValor.Text + "%' AND";
                Debug.Write(filter);
            }
            if (TextPesquisarDescricao.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " [Descricao] LIKE '%" + TextPesquisarDescricao.Text + "%' AND";
                Debug.Write(filter);
            }
            if (TextPesquisarCliente.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " [Cliente] LIKE '%" + TextPesquisarCliente.Text + "%' AND";
                Debug.Write(filter);
            }
            if (textValorcIva.Text != "")
            {
                filter = filter + " Valor > 0 LIKE '%" + textValorcIva.Text + "%' AND";
                Debug.Write(filter);

            }
            if (filter.Length > 0)
            {
                Sqldata.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
                string FinalFilter = filter.Remove(filter.Length - 3);
                SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = command + FinalFilter;
                Sqldata.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Sqldata.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: For security reasons you need to use parameterized SQL queries, see [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808).

Comment: I'm working doing stage for my school and I didnt start this program , it was half done by someone else , I'm new in this language so it´s hard for me to understand it and I must add new methods and contents and I can't change the previous code

Comment: @dbc is there any help you could give to me just to fix it ?

Comment: what do you check here " Valor > 0 LIKE '%" + textValorcIva.Text + "%' AND"

Comment: Compare the value with textbox if it the same it appears in gridview

Comment: as per my understand valor is your column name and if you given textValorcIva.Text values as 0 then it should return recordes which value is greter than 0 correct??

Comment: @MangeshAuti yes but it is not giving me that values , i don't know why!

Comment: @MangeshAuti maybe my problem here is the way i set textboxvalues as 0 can u say to me the easiest way to put it

Comment: check my answer .if not working paste Debug.Write(filter); value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
filter = filter + " Valor > 0 LIKE '%" + textValorcIva.Text + "%' AND";
```

to

```
filter = filter + " Valor > 0 AND Valor LIKE '%" + textValorcIva.Text + "%' AND";
```

Comment: Working but is there any way to only filter that numbers only higher than 0?

Comment: Sure: `filter = filter + " Valor > 0 AND Valor LIKE '%" + textValorcIva.Text + "%' AND";`

Comment: Thank you man , you're the man i needed for the past 3 days !

Comment: @HansKapitein don't you want to include your comment into your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change if block textValorcIva.Text to this (your query look like wrong)

```
if (textValorcIva.Text != "")
 {
     filter = filter + " Valor >"+ textValorcIva.Text + " AND";
     Debug.Write(filter);

 }
```

Comment: Yeh but my problem here is to set textbox valor as 0 as u said before

Comment: you means,automatically value of textValorcIva.Text =0 or else ?

Comment: is it automatically or need i to set textValorcIva.Text =0 ?

Comment: you can set before filter or outside if block textValorcIva.Text ="0" or directlly in filter as  filter = filter + " Valor >0 AND";

Comment: you can directly set  textValorcIva.Text default value as 0 in pageload event

Comment: before the block textValorcIva.Text = "0"; but it only put the 0 in the textbox does not get me the values

Comment: error ??   also you did change as per my answer in a query ?